# Why does only one of my Macs display iCloud tabs in Safari?

Tags: icloud, safari, imac

My iMac seems to have a problem with iCloud tabs.

On my iPhone and MacBook I can see Safari tabs from my iPhone, MacBook and iMac. However, on my iMac I do not have the option to add an iCloud tabs button on the toolbar, nor are tabs from my other devices shown when selecting "Show all tabs".

All 3 devices are running the latest OS and are on the same wifi network. The "Safari" box is ticked in iCloud settings on all 3 devices and iCloud tabs have worked previously.